# Problema al recopilar dato e imprimirlo en una tabla en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en C de hacer un inventario de una empresa, tengo varios errores para recopilar los datos e imprimir esos datos en una tabla.

Problema 1: se me cierra el programa al seleccionar la opción 1 de introducir los datos.
Problema 2:  ¿cómo puedo imprimir los datos recopilados en una tabla como esta?
[image: tabla]

> Crear un programa que registre el inventario de cada funcionario del departamento de ventas de la empresa.
>
> El proyecto presentara un menú de opciones las cuales serán:
>
> - Introduzca los datos necesarios para ejecutar el programa.
> - Introduzca el nombre y apellido del empleado

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)

{
    int opc1, opc2, opc3, edad, cedula, ncpu;
    char marca[5][10], genero[5], nombre[5][20], mcpu[5][10]; 

int i;


    
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf(">>>MENU DE LA EMPRESA<<<\n\n");
        printf("1. Ingresar datos\n");
        printf("2. Inventario de la empresa\n");
        printf("3. Cantidad de funcionarios menores de 25 anos\n");
        printf("4. Cantidad de funcionarios mayores de 40 anos\n");
        printf("5. Promedio de edad de los funcionarios\n");
        printf("6. Cantidad de funcionarios mujeres\n");
        printf("7. Cantidad de funcionarios homres\n");
        printf("8. Inventario por funcionario\n");
        printf("9. Mostrar las provincias de los funcionarios y numeros de cedula\n");
        printf("10. Salir\n\n");
        printf("Elija una Opcion:");
        scanf("%d",&opc1);
        switch(opc1)
        {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                switch(opc2);
                {
                    
                    for (i = 0;i <3; i++) 
                    {
                        printf("ingrese el nombre %s\n",i + 1);
                        scanf("%s",&nombre[i]);
                        printf("escoja el genero de %s\n",nombre[i]);
                        scanf("%s",&genero[i]);
                    
                        printf("Introduzca numero de Cedula del funcionario: %d\n");
                        scanf("%d",&cedula);
                        printf("Introduzca Edad del funcionario: %d\n" );
                        scanf("%d",&edad);
                        printf("Marca CPU: %s\n" );
                        scanf("%d",&mcpu);
                        printf("Numero activo de CPU: %s\n" );
                        scanf("%d",&ncpu);
                    }
                    printf("");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                printf(" \t\t\t\t *****  Inventario *****\n");
                       printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                       printf("|    Nombre     |  Numero de Cedula | Edad| Genero |  # Activo de CPU  | Marca del CPU |\n");
                       printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                for (i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    printf("%s -%d -%d -%s -%d -%d", nombre[i], cedula, edad, genero, ncpu, mcpu ); 
                }
                getch();
                break;
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                printf("");
                getch();
                break;
            case 4:
                system("cls");
                printf("");
                getch();
                break;
            case 5:
                system("cls");
                printf("");
                getch();
                break;      
            case 10:
                break;
            default:
                system("cls");
                printf("opcion incorrecta, presiona enter");
                getch();
                break;  
        }
    }while(opc1 !=10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La descripción de la pregunta debe ser mas precisa, no pongas el enunciado completo, sino, una descripción del problema (que es lo que está pasando?). Aun sigo sin entender cuales son los errores en ese programa...

Comment: editado la publicacion

Comment: Usa el principio [KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS), evita complicaciones. En este caso lo que debes hacer es agrupar la información del empleado en una [estructura](https://www.fing.edu.uy/tecnoinf/mvd/cursos/prinprog/material/teo/prinprog-teorico08.pdf) y luego creas un [array de N estructuras](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/c/c-array-of-structs/). Es lo mas simple que puedes lograr. La manera como lo estás haciendo no es lo ideal.

Answer (score 0):

> Problema 1: se me cierra el programa al seleccionar la opción 1 de introducir los datos.

Eso es porque estás tratanto mal la lectura de las cadenas de texto:

```
printf("ingrese el nombre %s\n",i + 1);
scanf("%s",&nombre[i]);
printf("escoja el genero de %s\n",nombre[i]);
scanf("%s",&genero[i]);
```

`scanf` necesita recibir un puntero a la variable donde se debe almacenar el dato, eso lo sabes. De lo que no te has percatado es de que tanto `nombre[i]` como `genero[i]` ya son punteros.

Los arrays son punteros simples:

```
char nombre[20];
```

Sin embargo las matrices son **punteros dobles**:

```
char nombre[5][20];
```

Es por ello que son capaces de recibir dos "*coordenadas*".

Así, si a un puntero doble le aplicas una indirección, lo que obtienes es un puntero simple:

```
char nombre[5][20]; // puntero doble
nombre[3];          // puntero simple
```

Así que, recapitulando, la lectura de cadenas de caracteres debería quedar así:

```
printf("ingrese el nombre %s\n",i + 1);
scanf("%s",nombre[i]);
//         ^ sin &
```

> Problema 2: ¿cómo puedo imprimir los datos recopilados en una tabla como esta?

El problema es facil de resolver si sabes cómo darle un tamaño a cada campo:

```
printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
printf("|    Nombre     |  Numero de Cedula | Edad | Genero | # Activo de CPU | Marca del CPU |\n");
printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

for( int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   printf("| %13s | %-17d | %-4d | %6s | %-15d | %-13d", nombre[i], cedula, edad, genero, ncpu, mcpu ); 
}
```

El número que sigue al `%` indica el tamaño del campo. El signo negativo es para alinear a la izquierda.